# How to obtain the complement of the $X = \{ (x,\frac{1}{x}), x > 0\}$

Tags: analysis

I need to prove that $X$ is a closed set. First i tried to show that every point of $X$ is adherent point and no one could be at less being of the form $(x,1/x)$ but i couldn't prove this second part. Then i wanna show that the complement of $X$ is a open set but a dont know how to define $X^{c}$.

Comment: Is $X$ a subset of $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: yes, it is $x \in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$(x,y) \mapsto xy.$$
This is a continuous function. As such, $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed. Note now that

$$X=f^{-1}(\{1\}) \cap \pi_1^{-1}\big([0,\infty)\big).$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We have $$X^c=\Big\{(x,y)\in (0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}:~y\neq 1/x\Big\}\cup \Big[(-\infty,0]\times \mathbb{R}\Big]$$
so $X^c$ is open, since for every $(x,y)\notin X$ we may find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $$\{(x',y')\in \mathbb{R}^2:~\|(x',y')-(x,y)\|_2=\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}<\varepsilon\}\subset X^c$$

(I assume you work on the Euclidean metric).

Answer (score 0):

You have $X= \{ (x,y) | x >0 \text{ and } xy=1 \}$. Note that if $x=0$ then
$xy = 0$, hence $(0,y) \notin X$ for all $y$, so we can write
$X= \{ (x,y) | x \ge 0 \text{ and } xy=1 \}$

It is easy to see that $X^c = \{ (x,y) | x<0 \}
\cup \{ (x,y) | xy \neq 1 \}$. Let the two sets be $U_1,U_2$ respectively.

We see that $U_1,U_2$ are open since the functions $(x,y) \mapsto x$ and $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ are continuous.